# How to perform offledger validation before endorsing/submitting a transaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Is there a way to automatically perform non-deterministic validation prior to endorsing/committing a transaction?

An example would be

1. to check if an document's proposed due-date does not fall on a specific organization's non working day.
2. to check if proposed currency exchange rate aligned with a data-source / market.

What would be recommended design pattern for this use case?